# Two Kafka console consumers stated with the same group id does not share the load

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Started the Zookeeper using the below command**

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Started Kafka broker**

```
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

**Created the topic using**

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic my-topic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

**Instantiated the console producer using**

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-topic
```

**Instantiated the console consumer using**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --from-beginning
```

**Instantiated second console consumer using**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --from-beginning
```

**Viewed the consumer groups using**

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

- console-consumer-37108
- console-consumer-15869

Stopped both the console consumers and then started 2 new console consumers with the same console group

**Terminal 1**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --group console-consumer-37108
```

**Terminal 2**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --group console-consumer-37108
```

Then published 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 using console producer. I was expecting 1,2,3,4 in Terminal 1 and the remaining 5,6,7,8 in Terminal 2. But to my surprise, all the messages 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 were consumed by Terminal 1 alone.

My understanding is messages should be equally distributed between two consumers, but it did not happen. Is my misunderstanding wrong? or was anything I did wrong here?
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a consumer problem. Consumer group cannot  assign the same partition to a consumer multiple times.

Kafka *producer* will batch many records together into one partition. This behavior changed around Kafka 2.8.

Partitions are not used for load balancing, only distribution of events.